# Correctly Installing Wifi Driver With patches from Github

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, make, github

I wish to install the driver in the following git.  https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723bs

Reading the documentation it appears I also need to install one or more patches.

My device is an HP Stream 7.  It has a baytrail processor.

I have Ubuntu server 32 bit with ubuntu desktop and gnome desktop installed on the device.  (So basically regular ubuntu 32 bit with an extra desktop.)

I am unsure which patches to apply.  Is it all the "pci-Fix-Device-hang-on Intel-Baytrail" or just the most recent one 4b?

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard and fast answer to this, the best advice I could give is to try and see what works.

The readme suggests that for your tablet, you'll need the first two patches, so apply and test those. Add the third if your kernel version is earlier then 4.3.